# IOS - I can't find super method allthough it is defined in the parent class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have 2 classes one is a parent of the other.
The `son` class is overriding the method called `textViewDidBeginEditing`
I want to use `super` to call the father method from the son class but I can't and the father method as it is not found and I cant reach it from the `son` class and I am getting the messege error
`No visible @interface for 'BaseViewController' declares the selector  'textViewDidBeginEditing'`
what do you think the problem should be?
It is not an import problem
and I have declared the method in the parent header file

her is my code

BaseViewController.h

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;

@end
```

BaseViewController.m

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@implementation BaseViewController


#pragma mark UITextView Delegate

- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)atextView {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

}
@end
```

SonViewController.h

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"
@interface SonViewController : BaseViewController 


@end
```

SonViewController.m

```
#import "SonViewController.h"

@implementation SonViewController 


#pragma mark UITextView Delegate

- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)atextView {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

}
@end
```

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: what error do you get when you run [super textViewDidBeginEditing];?

Comment: No visible @interface for 'BaseViewController' declares the selector 'textViewDidBeginEditing'

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to declare that method in your "father" class header file. It is a pure guess though.

Comment: Then you've forgotton to `#import` something.  Normally you would `#import "BaseClass.h"` in `DerivedClass.h` and then `#import "DerivedClass.h` in `DerivedClass.m`.  Have you done that?

Comment: Please some one formate the question..

Comment: this might be really simple - check that the method names are really the same.

Comment: it is not an import problem and I am trying the other suggestions

Comment: @PeterSarnowski method names are correct

Comment: post the relevant parts of the super and son classes.

Comment: Declare <UITextFieldDelegate> in header file of Father and implement the method. Then you would be able to invoke this method from your Son class.

Comment: I don't see a call to super anywhere in your code.